# Assistance with formatting/parsing JSON object in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

So I have the following code, and I keep getting a "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" error. What is formatted wrong? For context, the following is a list of articles that I read using a chrome extension and all I want to do is print the URL.

```
import json
json_data = "{
    "bookmarks": [
        {
            "article__excerpt": "i When Tom Wainwright became the Mexico correspondent for The Economist in 2010, he found himself covering the country's biggest businesses, including t",
            "favorite": true,
            "date_archived": "2016-02-17T15:38:46",
            "article__url": "http://www.npr.org/2016/02/15/466491812/narconomics-how-the-drug-cartels-operate-like-wal-mart-and-mcdonalds",
            "date_added": "2016-02-17T15:38:35",
            "date_favorited": "2016-02-17T15:38:33",
            "article__title": "'Narconomics': How The Drug Cartels Operate Like Wal-Mart And McDonald's",
            "archive": true
        },
        {
            "article__excerpt": null,
            "favorite": false,
            "date_archived": null,
            "article__url": "https://www.jacobinmag.com/2013/07/an-empire-of-our-lives/",
            "date_added": "2016-02-17T15:38:21",
            "date_favorited": null,
            "article__title": "https://www.jacobinmag.com/2013/07/an-empire-of-our-lives/",
            "archive": false
        },
        {
            "article__excerpt": "Socialism is love. For Valentine&#x2019;s Day, skip the flowers and chocolate and follow this link for $14.30 gift subscriptions. After a breakup a friend will inevitably turn to you over a drink,&hellip;",
            "favorite": false,
            "date_archived": null,
            "article__url": "https://www.jacobinmag.com/2016/02/internet-dating-commodification-love-valentine/",
            "date_added": "2016-02-17T15:37:37",
            "date_favorited": null,
            "article__title": "To Fall in Love, Click Here",
            "archive": false
        },
        {
    ],
    "recommendations": []
}"
data = json.loads(json_data)
for article in json_data["bookmarks"]:
    print(article["article__url"])
```

Comment: That whole strong is formatted wrong - you need to make it `"""multiline"""` to allow the quotes and line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Use triple quotes at the beginning and end of your json. This way newline characters won't break the string.

```
import json
json_data = """{
    "bookmarks": [
        {
            "article__excerpt": "i When Tom Wainwright became the Mexico correspondent for The Economist in 2010, he found himself covering the country's biggest businesses, including t",
            "favorite": true,
            "date_archived": "2016-02-17T15:38:46",
            "article__url": "http://www.npr.org/2016/02/15/466491812/narconomics-how-the-drug-cartels-operate-like-wal-mart-and-mcdonalds",
            "date_added": "2016-02-17T15:38:35",
            "date_favorited": "2016-02-17T15:38:33",
            "article__title": "'Narconomics': How The Drug Cartels Operate Like Wal-Mart And McDonald's",
            "archive": true
        },
        {
            "article__excerpt": null,
            "favorite": false,
            "date_archived": null,
            "article__url": "https://www.jacobinmag.com/2013/07/an-empire-of-our-lives/",
            "date_added": "2016-02-17T15:38:21",
            "date_favorited": null,
            "article__title": "https://www.jacobinmag.com/2013/07/an-empire-of-our-lives/",
            "archive": false
        },
        {
            "article__excerpt": "Socialism is love. For Valentine&#x2019;s Day, skip the flowers and chocolate and follow this link for $14.30 gift subscriptions. After a breakup a friend will inevitably turn to you over a drink,&hellip;",
            "favorite": false,
            "date_archived": null,
            "article__url": "https://www.jacobinmag.com/2016/02/internet-dating-commodification-love-valentine/",
            "date_added": "2016-02-17T15:37:37",
            "date_favorited": null,
            "article__title": "To Fall in Love, Click Here",
            "archive": false
        },
        {
    ],
    "recommendations": []
}"""
data = json.loads(json_data)
for article in json_data["bookmarks"]:
    print(article["article__url"])
```